# How can I find my next hop point for a home router?

Tags: router, isp

My ISP won't provide the ip address of the modem connection. They say they are not allowed to give that information out. On their end they can see the modem and program it with their ip address/subnet but they can't see/program your router. I have a Netgear modem and have tried to log into it with the default 192.168.100.1 but I get a message saying to check the connection. I have tried turning off all my firewalls on my computer and plugging the cable directly from computer to modem. When I ping it it says "reply from (my device ip address): Destination host unreachable". If I could get into the modem I could see what the ip address and subnet is that they are using to connect to the internet. I am wondering if I could get it by erasing the cisco router start-up config, then power cycle the router, and put in the command "ip dhcp client request router" on the internet interface.

Comment: This doesnt make any sense at all.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hook up this router to my modem so I can use the internet on this cisco router.  The other router I have works fine but it is a plug and play router that automatically gets all the information it needs.  With cisco you have to program everything in the command line to set it up.  Are you not familiar with cisco routers?

Comment: A traceroute to an external site should be all that's required.

Comment: Re-connect the old router. See what IP address it gets. I'm not sure why you can't just set the Cisco to DHCP; that tends to be default for WAN. BTW, it is very unlikely to be a 192 adress.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your provider's position as I think it's completely stupid to try to hide from user the IP address of the modem - this doesn't serve any reasonable purpose.

If you plugged the computer directly into the modem and the Internet connection is working on the computer, you should be able to get the information you need from network settings of your computer. Check what default gateway your computer is using.